# pip failed to install psycopg2. Installed via apt-get, but build folder remains

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, psycopg2

I'm trying to get started on Django via Heroku. Their guide recommends I install psycopg2.

I installed Django and some dj-library manager of some kind with `pip` with no problems, but `psycopg2` kept demanding files I didn't have. Some solutions recommended installing `python-dev` and another package, but I decided to try `sudo apt-get` and it worked, and even `pip` recognizes `psycopg2` as installed now.

The only problem is that I ran the console for the failed installation in my newly minted "Projects" folder, and now there's a Build folder sitting there waiting for pip to finish the job it started. How do I get rid of it?

Also, I am *really* new at Ubuntu/Django/Python-in-linux, so feel free to correct any misunderstandings I've gathered so far.

Comment: also for the first time ever I notice the bar underneath the main site showing different SO hubs. If this question can be ported to a more appropriate environment, I'd appreciate some instruction in how to do so.

Comment: You're not just asking how to remove a given directory, are you?

Comment: I tried to sudo remove the directory and access was denied. I need to somehow tell pip to stop protecting those files, because I don't need its installation process anymore.

Comment: did you do `sudo rm -r Build`? If sudo is working properly, there are very few reasons access would be denied.

Comment: I was typing something slightly different I found on a website, but it included sudo rm and build. however, that exact command you posted did work.

I'll hold out in case someone wants to tell me how to let pip do it, but thanks!

Comment: Went ahead and made it an answer. I don't think there's really any more to it than that. pip can't protect files, so what it sounds like happened is you did `sudo pip install psychopg2` and then all intermediate files that were created were owned by root. I have a feeling those files were more psychopg2's output than pip's, and it's a little strange that pip would leave them in your Project dir, but who knows...

Comment: Oh, and could you edit the question to include the command you tried to remove the dir and the error it gave you (if you still have access to it) so people can see it w/o having to go digging through these comments? It's kind of important info to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're not doing a recursive rm:

```
sudo rm -r Build
```

If sudo is working properly, there are very few reasons access would be denied.